# react-native - fetch: Network request failed

Tags: typescript, react-native, ssl, fetch, expo

I am developing a app using React Native and expo. I want to fetch an API but I get this error.

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Network request failed]
- node_modules\whatwg-fetch\dist\fetch.umd.js:541:17 in setTimeout$argum
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:130:14 in 
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:383:16 in 
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:416:
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:109:
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:
14 in _callTimer
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:383:16 in callTimers   
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:416:4 in __callFunction
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:109:6 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:108:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

Fetching another url (like: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1") works fine. And when I paste the exact same url in my Browser it also works fine. The weird thing is that it works sometimes.

I suspect it has something to do with the ssl certification, because when running a ssl test over it it shows "chain issues". I can't fix the ssl cerficat, but is there a way to ignore the incomplete ssl certification?

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your application tag in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

This will allow "HTTP" calls. it is by default disabled on API 28 or higher devices.

If this is on ios add this in your info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: The problem is that I use a Managed Expo project, so I can't change the AndroidManidest.xml or the info.plist.

Comment: Same issue here, Did you get the soulation?